# How can i dim a light component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two lights components. First i'm finding both Lights and disable them.
Then I want to enable them when changing some object scale and using the object scaling duration time for the lights dim.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DimLights : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Lights Change
    public Light[] lightsToDim = null;
    public float maxTime;

    private GameObject[] myLights;
    private float mEndTime = 0;
    private float mStartTime = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        myLights = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Light");
        mStartTime = Time.time;
        mEndTime = mStartTime + maxTime;
        LightsState(false);
    }

    public void LightsState(bool state)
    {
        foreach (GameObject go in myLights)
        {
            go.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = state;
        }
    }

    public void LightDim()
    {
        foreach (Light light in lightsToDim)
        {
            light.intensity = Mathf.InverseLerp(mStartTime, mEndTime, Time.time);
        }
    }
}
```

The second script is scaling some object:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChangeScale : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Scaling change
    public GameObject objectToScale;
    public float duration = 1f;
    public Vector3 minSize;
    public Vector3 maxSize;

    private bool scaleUp = false;
    private Coroutine scaleCoroutine;

    //Colors change
    public Color startColor;
    public Color endColor;
    public float colorDuration; // duration in seconds

    private void Start()
    {
        startColor = GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color;
        endColor = Color.green;
        objectToScale.transform.localScale = minSize;
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            //Flip the scale direction when F key is pressed
            scaleUp = !scaleUp;

            //Stop old coroutine
            if (scaleCoroutine != null)
                StopCoroutine(scaleCoroutine);

            //Scale  up
            if (scaleUp)
            {
                //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
                scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaleOverTime(objectToScale, maxSize, duration));
            }

            //Scale Down
            else
            {
                //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
                scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaleOverTime(objectToScale, minSize, duration));
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
        {
            StartCoroutine(ChangeColor());
        }
    }

    IEnumerator scaleOverTime(GameObject targetObj, Vector3 toScale, float duration)
    {
        float counter = 0;

        //Get the current scale of the object to be scaled
        Vector3 startScaleSize = targetObj.transform.localScale;

        while (counter < duration)
        {
            counter += Time.deltaTime;
            targetObj.transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(startScaleSize, toScale, counter / duration);
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator ChangeColor()
    {
        float t = 0;

        while (t < colorDuration)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime;
            GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.Lerp(startColor, endColor, t / colorDuration);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

In the second script the ChangeScale i want inside the scaleOverTime method to dim the light using the method LightDim in the DimLights script.

Comment: You never mentioned when the light should dim and when it should get brighter.

Comment: @Programmer Right, When scaling up it should get brighter and scaling down should dim until turn off.

Comment: All the lights in the array should do this?

Comment: Yes, All the lights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that complicated. You change the `scaleOverTime` function to work on light by copying it making a new function from it. The only thing to change is the `Vector3.Lerp` function to `Mathf.Lerp` function and also `targetObj.transform.localScale`  to `targetObj.intensity`.

A simple Light dim function:

```
IEnumerator dimLightOverTime(Light targetObj, float toIntensity, float duration)
{
    float counter = 0;

    //Get the current intensity of the Light 
    float startIntensity = targetObj.intensity;

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;
        targetObj.intensity = Mathf.Lerp(startIntensity, toIntensity, counter / duration);
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, you are using an array so the function should be made to take an array:

```
IEnumerator dimLightOverTime(Light[] targetObj, float toIntensity, float duration)
{
    float counter = 0;
    //Get the current intensity of the Light 
    float[] startIntensity = new float[targetObj.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < targetObj.Length; i++)
    {
        startIntensity[i] = targetObj[i].intensity;
    }

    while (counter < duration)
    {
        counter += Time.deltaTime;

        for (int i = 0; i < targetObj.Length; i++)
        {
            targetObj[i].intensity = Mathf.Lerp(startIntensity[i], toIntensity, counter / duration);
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

This prevents having to start new coroutine for each `Light` and saving some time.

The new `Update` function:

```
public Light[] lightsToDim = null;
private Coroutine lightCoroutine;

// Use this for initialization
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        //Flip the scale direction when F key is pressed
        scaleUp = !scaleUp;

        //Stop old coroutine
        if (scaleCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(scaleCoroutine);

        if (lightCoroutine != null)
            StopCoroutine(lightCoroutine);


        //Scale  up
        if (scaleUp)
        {
            //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
            scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaleOverTime(objectToScale, maxSize, duration));
            lightCoroutine = StartCoroutine(dimLightOverTime(lightsToDim, 1, duration)); ;
        }

        //Scale Down
        else
        {
            //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
            scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaleOverTime(objectToScale, minSize, duration));
            lightCoroutine = StartCoroutine(dimLightOverTime(lightsToDim, 0, duration)); ;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the new variable "`lightCoroutine`". That's used to store the old coroutine just like we did for the `scaleCoroutine`.